# Trick for overloads

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    template <typename... Args> void execute(Args&&... args) {foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}
    template <typename... Args> void doIt(Args&&... args) {bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}
private:
    void foo() {}
    void foo(int) {}
    void foo(int, char) {}
    void foo(bool, int, double) {}
    void bar() {foo();}  // *** Added
    void bar(int) {}
    void bar(int num, char c) {foo(num, c);}  // *** Added
    void bar(bool, int, double) {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.doIt();
    a.doIt(5,'t');
}
```

`A::doIt` is to have the same overloading types as `A::execute` and will use `bar`'s overloads for some of them (for which bar's overloads are unique) and use `foo`'s overloads for the others.  To get this done, I simply added `void bar() {foo();}` and `void bar(int num, char c) {foo(num, c);}`.  This is not that painful, but suppose there were many such forwarding to do.  And think of the maintenance issues when new overloads of `doIt` are needed, and new `foo` overloads defined for them (easy to forget the forwarding stuff).

Is there a way to remove these extra `bar` overloads (that simply forward to `foo`), and instead modify the currently defined `doIt(Args&&... args)` function so that in case no such bar overload exists it will call up `foo`'s overloads instead?  So in other words, remove the two `bar` overloads that I added, and still have main() compile as intended due to `doIt`'s new definition.

Comment: May be some partial specialization.

Comment: You mean use std::enable if, std::declval and such?  How to take care of all the argument types?

Comment: Something like this, yes. SFINAE. _"How to take care of all the argument types? "_ Forwarding as you already do probably. I'm not aware of a ready made solution for your concerns now, but that's the directory I'd try looking up.

Comment: You could split `A` into `A_bar` and `A_foo`, rename all `bar`s to `foo` and let `A_foo` inherit from `A_bar`.

Comment: If you want to go that route, then add a `using A_foo::foo;` in `A_bar`, otherwise the declarations of `foo` in `A_foo` are hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SFINAE on the well-formedness of `bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

```
class A {
private:
    void foo();
    void foo(int);
    void foo(int, char);
    void foo(bool, int, double);
    void bar(int);
    void bar(bool, int, double);

    template <typename... Args> 
    auto doIt_impl(int, Args&&... args) -> decltype(bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){
        bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    template <typename... Args> 
    auto doIt_impl(long, Args&&... args) -> void {
        foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

public:
    template <typename... Args> void doIt(Args&&... args) {
        doIt_impl(0, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

The dummy first parameter ensures that the `bar`-calling overload of `doIt_impl` is preferred if viable. Also, it's important to note that trailing return types do not get class-scope lookup, so the declaration of `doIt_impl` must be after the declaration of the `bar`s.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3442d1d04c68dfd6).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nwp's hint (though I'm not sure if this is what he meant), and T.C.'s debugging hint, I have this alternate solution.  But T.C.'s solution is way better.

```
#include <iostream>

class A_Foo {
protected:
    virtual void foo() {std::cout << "foo().\n";}
    virtual void foo(int) {std::cout << "foo(int).\n";}
    virtual void foo(int, char) {std::cout << "foo(int, char).\n";}
    virtual void foo(bool, int, double) {std::cout << "foo(bool, int, double).\n";}
};

class A_Bar : private A_Foo {
public:
    using A_Foo::foo;  // This is needed.  Else all the declarations of foo in A_Foo are hidden.
    virtual void foo(int) override {std::cout << "bar(int).\n";}
    virtual void foo(bool, int, double) override {std::cout << "bar(bool, int, double).\n";}
};

class A : private A_Bar {
public:
    template <typename... Args> void execute(Args&&... args) {
        A_Foo::foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    template <typename... Args> void doIt(Args&&... args) {
        A_Bar::foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.doIt();  // foo().
    a.doIt(5);  // bar(int).
    a.doIt(5,'t');  // foo(int, char).
    a.doIt(true,5,1.8);  // bar(bool, int, double).
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `virtual` - all your calls are non-virtual anyway.